# Conditions in python that are not hard-coded

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements, isin

I am trying to find a way to represent conditions for `np.where()` other than from within the code. In my example below,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file='insert path'
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df.loc[:, ['col_a','col_b']] = df.loc[:, ['col_a','col_b']].astype(str)
dfseg=df['col_a']+'-'+df['col_b']+'-'+df['col_c']

df['col_d'] = np.where((df['col_a']=='101')|(df['col_a']=='337')|(df['col_a']=='524'),dfseg,df['col_a'])

df
```

the conditions are that

a. df['col_a']=='101' or

b. df['col_a']=='337' or

c. df['col_a']=='524'

Is there any way these conditions could be represented external to the code? Or through another python method/function? Can `tkinter` extract this portion of the code and edit these conditions? Hoping to find a way these conditions could be reviewed and managed, etc. externally rather than within the script.

I have tried `np.isin()` and `np.in1d` but received False results:

```
print(np.in1d(df1['col_a'],df2['col_a']))
print(np.isin(df1['col_a'],df2['col_a']))
```

Output:

```
[False False False False False False]
[False False False False False False]
```

From the following:

```
df2: 
    col_a
0    101
1    524
2    337 
 df1: 
   col_a col_b col_c
0   101   104   AAB
1   337   103   CAD
2   524   204   DER
3   129   404   EEH
4   842   108   HHR
5   337   108   HHE 
 df2[col_a].isin df1[col_a] 
 0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: col_a, dtype: bool 
 df1[col_a].isin df2[col_a] 
 0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: col_a, dtype: bool
```

Converting df to numpy with

```
df1numpy = df1.to_numpy()
```

Similarly yielded all "False" matches with `np.isin()`. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: If it's always `col_a`, you can just put the comparison value in a variable.

Comment: You can also put the column name in a variable. Then it's `df[col_name] == col_value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, after converting df to numpy, the array needs to be transposed as well:

```
df1numpy1stcol = np.transpose(df1numpy)[0]
```

(df2 does not need to be converted to numpy, updated below).

Then, change datatype from object:

```
df1numpy1stcol.astype(np.int32)
```

Finally, the `np.where()` could be used with `np.isin()`:

```
df1['col_d'] = np.where(np.isin(df1numpy1stcol.astype(np.int32),df2),
                       dfseg,df1['col_a'])
```

thus, df1 [output] as:

|  | col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 101 | 104 | AAB | 101-104-AAB |
| 1 | 337 | 103 | CAD | 337-103-CAD |
| 2 | 524 | 204 | DER | 524-204-DER |
| 3 | 129 | 404 | EEH | 129 |
| 4 | 842 | 108 | HHR | 842 |
| 5 | 337 | 108 | HHE | 337-108-HHE |

The exceptions list is now represented as an editable list named "df2".